# Actions on Google (Handle fallback)

Tags: actions-on-google

I have a query on a Google home (Dialogflow).

In a specific, after I execute fallback intent three times it exits with a statement

> Sorry I can't help

But it should prompt

> I am ending this session see you again later.

Here is code of fallback intent

```js
app.intent('Default Fallback Intent', (conv) => 
{
    const repromptCount = parseInt(conv.arguments.get('REPROMPT_COUNT'));
    if (repromptCount === 0) { conv.ask(`Hey are you listening?`); } 
    else if (repromptCount === 1) { conv.ask(`Are you still around?`); } 
    else if (conv.arguments.get('IS_FINAL_REPROMPT')) { conv.close(`I am ending this session see you again later.`); }
});
```

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Is this happening when you say something triggered by the fallback intent, or if you say nothing? Are you using the Actions SDK or Dialogflow? Can you update your question to show a sample dialog where this is happening, or possibly show the fulfillment code you're using to handle the fallback intent?

Comment: @Prisoner is this information enough?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you're trying to follow the directions in the [documentation about dynamic reprompts](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/reprompts#dynamic_reprompts) for "no-input" type responses.

The problem appears to be that you're trying to use this for the Fallback Intent, which is not specifically triggered on a NO_INPUT event. So it is doing the test, and neither the REPROMPT_COUNT nor IS_FINAL_REPROMPT arguments are set.

If you're using the [multivocal library](https://multivocal.info/), it will keep counters of all the Intents and Actions that are called (both for the session and sequentially) and has some macros that assist in your responses.

If you want to use the existing library, you'll need to keep track of this yourself and either store this in a Context or store it in the session data object.

If you intended to use this as part of a "no-input" response, you need to make sure you're using this with an Intent that has the `actions_intent_NO_INPUT` event set.

Comment: If the answer helped you, upvoting and/or accepting it is always appreciated. If you found another solution, sharing your solution as an answer will help others who have the same problem as you did.

Comment: I upvoted for your solution and will even keep in mind to share my solution.